# Error in downloading Files with Import range function

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I use Google Drive API to download files from Drive to the local system and my script is written in JAVA.

My code download files as CSV and if there are multiple sheets in Google Sheet it will download each sheet as a different CSV file.

From past 2 days if there is an Importrange formula in a google then it is getting downloaded with contents in cells as **""IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""),"57471""**

[image: Sample Image of how data looks in downloaded file]

Comment: Does the value for that fomula belongs to other sheets of the Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug that surfaced in recent weeks in Google Spreadsheets.

[Downloading File with importrange function failing - think it's a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739319/downloading-file-with-importrange-function-failing-think-its-a-bug)

[Thread on Google Docs Help Forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/mZBoUuEXLxQ;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Atroubleshoot%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false)

I tried the fix suggested in the first link (putting a data validation on) but it didn't work for me. I guess we all have to wait until it's fixed by Google.

Comment: I suggested few workarounds on the linked SO question.