# Downloading File with importrange function failing - think it's a bug

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-drive-api, export

I've been saving Google Sheets to Excel without any problems for a while. These sheets have always successfully saved and opened in Excel with the importrange function. However, recently it hasn't been successfully saving correctly.

It used to just have the static value (e.g, 40). There used to be an IFERROR in the first cell in the header row **but now it exists in every single cell.**

E.g, each cell would have something like this:

```
=IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION(importrange(blahblah)),"40").
```

`DUMMYFUNCTION` throws an error and "40" is returned as a result. but "40" is a string, not an integer which messes up all my formulas.

I also know this isn't an Excel issue because OpenOffice is doing the same thing with the file.

I'm pretty sure this would be a bug because why would it be working for months and then suddenly stop working?

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it's a bug too.

## Workarounds

### On Excel

- Copy and paste as values only the ranges with `IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION(...`, then use Excel's UI tools to convert numbers shown as text to numbers.
- Selectively remove quotes on the IFERROR second argument of the cells causing problems
- Remove `=IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION(),"value")` except `value` (we could use Excel's built-in FIND &  REPLACE for this)

### On Google Sheets

- Use Copy > Paste as values only on the range areas having formulas with non-compatible functions like IMPORTRANGE, QUERY, FILTER, etc.
- If you only need the values, download it as CSV instead of XLSX

## IMPORTANT

In order to help to prioritize this issue, send feedback to Google. To do this open a Google Sheets spreadsheet, click on Help > Report a problem, then fill the feedback form and submit it.

## Related stuff

I posted 5 small articles about this in Spanish. You could find them listed on https://www.rubenrivera.mx/p/descargar-hcg-excel.html.

Answer (score 0):

We accidentally created a workaround for this bug with a different sheet that was just set up like this.

This works when you IMPORTRANGE into another Google Sheet. We are doing it into a Google Sheet with a single worksheet - haven't tried it with multiple.

It's going to sound a little nuts but it works for us.

In the first cell of your import range put a hyperlink in the original document you are importing from. This is in the *first cell of the import range*. We linked it to a worksheet in the original document. It has worked and failed with an external link. With an external link it worked when I linked it to an internal link, then changed it. But when I deleted the cell and just straight linked it to an external URL it didn't work.

Then @timbo was right - put data validation in. This can be in part of the document that isn't being imported into the second sheet. I put it in the first line of the import range but outside what I was importing. It might have to be the first line. I just put a date in one cell, then in the next cell data > data validation > then choose that one date as the data range.

For aesthetics I have hidden the first row in one Google Sheet I am importing into. In another I made the first cell link the title of the sheet and put the data validation outside the import range. Both of these work.

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Until this bug is fixed, a workaround is to put a data validation (Data > Data Validation) on the imported data (Any kind of data validation will do).