# Google Sheets Macro to Save File as Excel File with Pasted Value

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I currently have a Google spreadsheet that is using an `IMPORTRANGE` formula to populate data from a source sheet. Now, I realize when downloading the file to excel, every cell from the `IMPORTRANGE` has a formula showing as:

```
=IFERROR(__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE"""),"[text from google sheet]")
```

I would like to see if I can create a macro that would paste values and also save as an excel file, but the problem with with Google Sheets is it saves all changes as they happen. So, pasting values would do that for the sheet and I would looks the `IMPORTRANGE` formulas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome. The question is not clear enough for this site as it doesn't include anything about where did you get stuck and anything about your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask]. Please improve your question.

Comment: Related: [Downloading File with importrange function failing - think it's a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51739319/1595451)